# .onDelete not working in sorted ForEach - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have no clue on why this is not working. I've always done it the same way, the only difference is the `sorted` method.

```swift
ForEach(userData.fruits_and_vegetables.sorted { $0.item < $1.item}) { grocery in
  DetailCardView(item: grocery.item, itemCount: grocery.count)
}.onDelete { (offset) in
  self.userData.fruits_and_vegetables.remove(atOffsets: offset)
}
```

Help! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You get `offset` of one array, but tries to apply it to another one... really won't work.

Instead it should be done, like

```
let sorted = userData.fruits_and_vegetables.sorted { $0.item < $1.item}

...

ForEach(sorted) { grocery in
  DetailCardView(item: grocery.item, itemCount: grocery.count)
}.onDelete { (offset) in
    for i in offset {
        if let found = self.userData.fruits_and_vegetables.firstIndex(where: { $0 == sorted[i] }) {
            self.userData.fruits_and_vegetables.remove(at: found)
        }
    }
}
```

and better move `sorted` and content of `onDelete` into your `userData` class.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem.
In `remove` function I add the same sort:

```
func remove(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
          let grocery = userData.fruits_and_vegetables.sorted { $0.item < $1.item }[index]
              grocery.delete // Your delete method
    }
}
```

In my code I also had a `.filter`, which I added there too. Everything works!

Comment: FYI: You were voted down on this "answer" by people because you're not answering the question asked and instead just adding a "Me too". If you have a simalar question that isn't answered here then post your own question with enough information on how to reproduce it (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to do that).